# How to remove one key in JanusGraph or Titan Mixed index？

Tags: janusgraph

For example:

there are three keys in a mixed index named "personIndex", they are "name" and "age" and "uri", how to remove "uri" from personIndex?

I don't find any way or any methods to do this in the sourcecode or in the JanusGraph's  Documentation .

thank you very much !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to remove a key from an index that was already defined. You have to create a new index.

Comment: thanks for your answer ,but i have another question: how to delete a mixed  index ? i have disabled a mixed index with gremlin , should i have to delete a mixed index at the storge backend?

Comment: Please see the JanusGraph docs on [index removal](http://docs.janusgraph.org/latest/index-admin.html#mr-index-removal).